# Joomla - Hide images on Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

Is there a way to hide images on Joomla when viewing an article on a mobile device?
I have googled but could not really find anything that is not specific to certain templates.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template is using bootstrap, add corresponding class to the image: hidden-phone for 2.3 or hidden-sm for bootstrap 3

Comment: Thanks Radek. I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Radek, one more question for you please. Now that I am not displaying the image, is there a way I can increase the size of the div automatically in a similar way? The div on desktop is set at 85% width to leave space for the image.

Comment: Actually I found it:

Class Phones
767px and below
Tablets
979px to 768px
Desktops
Default
.visible-phone Visible Hidden Hidden
.visible-tablet Hidden Visible Hidden
.visible-desktop Hidden Hidden Visible
.hidden-phone Hidden Visible Visible
.hidden-tablet Visible Hidden Visible
.hidden-desktop Visible Visible Hidden